# Jupyter Notebook 500 Internal server Error anaconda3

Tags: python, json, jupyter-notebook

I recently uninstalled anaconda and could not get into the jupyter notebook. I type it in terminal it opens, but when I want to create a python kernel it just gives big internal server error. I cannot access anything I have been working on. Especially it seems to have a problem with permission.

```
[W 14:02:05.164 NotebookApp] 404 GET /static/components/marked/lib/marked.js?v=20230223140159 (::1) 9.930000ms referer=http://localhost:8888/tree
[E 14:02:07.550 NotebookApp] Uncaught exception GET /notebooks/python_class_1_students%20-%20automatic_populating.ipynb (::1)
    HTTPServerRequest(protocol='http', host='localhost:8888', method='GET', uri='/notebooks/python_class_1_students%20-%20automatic_populating.ipynb', version='HTTP/1.1', remote_ip='::1')
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/moniowariacie/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1713, in _execute
        result = await result
      File "/Users/moniowariacie/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 782, in run
        yielded = self.gen.send(value)
      File "/Users/moniowariacie/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/notebook/notebook/handlers.py", line 94, in get
        self.write(self.render_template('notebook.html',
      File "/Users/moniowariacie/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/notebook/base/handlers.py", line 511, in render_template
        return template.render(**ns)
      File "/Users/moniowariacie/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 1301, in render
        self.environment.handle_exception()
      File "/Users/moniowariacie/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 936, in handle_exception
        raise rewrite_traceback_stack(source=source)
      File "/Users/moniowariacie/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/notebook/templates/notebook.html", line 1, in top-level template code
        {% extends "page.html" %}
      File "/Users/moniowariacie/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/notebook/templates/page.html", line 166, in top-level template code
        {% block header %}
      File "/Users/moniowariacie/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/notebook/templates/notebook.html", line 115, in block 'header'
        {% for exporter in get_frontend_exporters() %}
      File "/Users/moniowariacie/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/notebook/notebook/handlers.py", line 40, in get_frontend_exporters
        for name in get_export_names():
      File "/Users/moniowariacie/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nbconvert/exporters/base.py", line 146, in get_export_names
        e = get_exporter(exporter_name)(config=config)
      File "/Users/moniowariacie/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nbconvert/exporters/base.py", line 103, in get_exporter
        if getattr(exporter(config=config), 'enabled', True):
      File "/Users/moniowariacie/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nbconvert/exporters/templateexporter.py", line 332, in __init__
        super().__init__(config=config, **kw)
      File "/Users/moniowariacie/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nbconvert/exporters/exporter.py", line 118, in __init__
        self._init_preprocessors()
      File "/Users/moniowariacie/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nbconvert/exporters/templateexporter.py", line 499, in _init_preprocessors
        conf = self._get_conf()
      File "/Users/moniowariacie/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nbconvert/exporters/templateexporter.py", line 519, in _get_conf
        if conf_path.exists():
      File "/Users/moniowariacie/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/pathlib.py", line 1424, in exists
        self.stat()
      File "/Users/moniowariacie/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/pathlib.py", line 1232, in stat
        return self._accessor.stat(self)
    PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/share/jupyter/nbconvert/templates/conf.json'
[E 14:02:07.567 NotebookApp] {
      "Host": "localhost:8888",
      "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
      "Referer": "http://localhost:8888/tree",
      "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/16.3 Safari/605.1.15"
    }
[E 14:02:07.567 NotebookApp] 500 GET /notebooks/python_class_1_students%20-%20automatic_populating.ipynb (::1) 572.990000ms referer=http://localhost:8888/tree
```

It seems to try to access the file that does not exist. I do not have the path on my mac that is called /usr/local/share. I know he is opening on a local server but why? Can't I change the path of this accessed file, so it would trace it to the place where anaconda is really installed?

I tried everything I found on stackoverflow, which is reinstalling anaconda, upgrading it, upgrading jupyter, reinstalling jupyter, installing the nbconverter, trying to access it using sudo command. I know macs have their own python and this is the one they are trying to access. I do not know how to trace this terminal still. I can provide all the information needed.

Comment: Which command do you use to start jupyter?